# What does it mean that a certain building is "architecture become mathematics"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests, phrase-meaning

I read about the Citigroup Center in NYC in a travel guide, and one sentence said that this building, designed as a graph-paper, is "architecture become mathematics". What does it mean?

Comment: What do you think it means? And why do you think what you think it means is not what it really means?

Comment: I thought it meant something like - that building's design is inspired by math elements. I want to be sure because English is not my native language and I need it for my grade.

Comment: You sure it wasn't more along the lines of: "mathematics become architecture"?

Comment: Yes, quoting from the text, it goes like this: "the graph-paper design sheathed in aluminum is architecture become mathematics".

Comment: You should edit the complete context into the Q...many people here are not as patient as I am....and give a link or source, please.

Answer (score 1):

It is a poetic phrase (as is shown by the very literary use of [whiz-deletion](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=24650) with *become*).

As with much poetry, the precise meaning is hard to determine. The literal meaning is something like "This building started off as architecture but has turned into mathematics". Since this is clearly nonsense as an objective, literal statement, it must be poetry.

("Is become" is an archaic form of "has become".)

[For the sake of clarity: I'm not saying that this is an established poetic phrase, or a quotation from anywhere: it's probably newly coined, but it is intended to be taken poetically].